# PHP and using header

Tags: php

I have a login page that contains a variable $blogid which "gets" the blog id number from a previous page.  the code is `$blogid = strip_tags(htmlentities(stripslashes($_GET['blog'])));`  After a user logs in I need to pass the user id and blog id to another page (comments_post.php)  I have the following code

```
        $_SESSION['user'] = $userrow[0];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $userpass;

        die(header("Location: comments_post.php?blog=1&user=$userrow[0]"));
```

The redirect passes the blog id as 1 and the correct user id number (from a table).  I need the statement to pass the blog id number that is defined by $blogid.  if I change the code to blog=$blogid only the user id is passed.  How do I get the $blogid variable to pass to comments_post.php?

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
die(header('Location: comments_post.php?blog=' . $blogid . '&user= ' . $userrow[0]));
```

Also are you sure $blogid is defined?

Comment: 10 yrs of PHP programming and putting exit() after header redirects only now to realize from your answer it would have made more sense to put the redirect inside it. I'd give +50 if I could, but +1 it is! =o)

Comment: Yes $blogid is defined.  if I echo $blogid on the page, I can see the correct blog id number.

Comment: I tried your format.  When I see the comment post page, the blog id and user id numbers appear at the bottom (like   4  15). The first number being the blog id.  This is what I got ' . . ' ' . 15

Comment: I tried '$blogid' as well and got basically the same results   ' '  15

Comment: @learner what's in the URL on the page you have redirected to?

Comment: It is the page where the user/visitor would enter a comment and it would be posted in a comments table. A comment does post but a value of "0" is entered in the blog id field...as it is now.

Comment: In the url you will see http://website/manage/comments_post.php?blog=&user=12 It should show the blogid as well such as blog=20&user=12

Comment: I have spent a countless number of hours trying to solve this problem. I do not understand why I can see $blogid on this page and I can't pass it.  Okay, my login page is included on a blog article page and that is where #blogid is defined. The login page, of course, contains a form.  I can display the blog id underneath the form, but I can't pass it with the header function. Please feel free to contact me directly.

Comment: @learner in that case $blogid is not defined on the page with the above code snippet at the point you call that code.

Comment: Can you show the complete code including where $blogid is set?

Comment: Okay, I found the problem.  I had to add blog=$blogid in the action section of the form. Like this action="manage/comments_login.php?blog=$blogid"  this corrected the problem.  Thanks for your help.